# color segments in radarchart

Tags: r, plot, colors, rcharts

I recently discovered the rcharts package an was able to make a chart. 
Now I would like to color segments in the radar chart. Any ideas?
Below is a simplified example to work on:

```
library(rCharts)
#create dummy dataframe with number ranging from 0 to 1
df<-data.frame(id=c("a","b","c","d","e"),val1=runif(5,0,1),val2=runif(5,0,1))
#muliply number by 100 to get percentage
df[,-1]<-df[,-1]*100

plot <- Highcharts$new()
plot$chart(polar = TRUE, type = "line",height=500)
plot$xAxis(categories=df$id, tickmarkPlacement= 'on', lineWidth= 0)
plot$yAxis(gridLineInterpolation= 'circle', lineWidth= 0, min= 0,max=100,endOnTick=T,tickInterval=10)
plot$series(data = df[,"val1"],name = "Series 1", pointPlacement="on")
plot$series(data = df[,"val2"],name = "Series 2", pointPlacement="on")
plot
```

Resulting in a plot like this:

[image: rachrt]

Now I would like to produce this plot:

[image]

Comment: Technically that is a pie chart with equal pie size. I do not now highchart - but I think with `ggplot2` you might arrive at this if you make the colors transparent.